# Issue with background scrollbar showing through modal in Safari only

Tags: css, user-interface, safari

I'm tracking down an issue where the scrollbar on the page is showing through the modal in Safari only. I've found no conflicts with the z-index or anything and I'm wondering if it's an issue with Safari? Have any of you come across something like this before?

The modal has a position of `fixed`

[image: Modal window that shows the scrollbar from the background page bleeding through]